# R: How to convert factors into numeric for a DATA FRAME?

Tags: r, integer, coercion

I want to convert factors into numeric. I know this a FAQ, I tried already `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` and `as.numeric(as.character(f))`. But this doesn't help as I want to convert all columns (more than 1000 and all of type factor) of the df into numeric. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe an example of your data? Also I guess you import that with read.table. If that's the case try stringsAsFactors=F

Comment: Why do you have columns that are of class factor and should be numeric? That's the question you should be investigating.

Comment: Just to clarify -- do you want to convert the **value** of the factor to numeric, or the **level**?  In other words, if my levels were "10", "1000", and "100000" -- what should these become?  Do the values have other symbols in them ("$100,000") that are preventing `read.table` from recognizing them as numeric?

Comment: Sorry for late answer: I want the values not levels. I read the data using read.csv(). I have more columns that are really factors (first 10 cols), that is just a subset of columns 11:n. Is maybe there a way to assign to this column numeric by read.csv?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can try

```
 yourdat[] <- lapply(yourdat, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
                              else x)
```

Comment: Why `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` and not just `as.numeric(x)` since we know x is a factor ?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  Try `v1 <- factor(c(1, 132, 27)); as.numeric(v1)`

Comment: right -- I'm not sure which of these conversions the OP actually wants.  I guess we'll find out if he accepts your answer.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  I just noticed that all the columns are `factors`.  In that case the `if/else` condition is not needed.

Comment: `as.data.frame(lapply(yourdat, function(x)  as.numeric(levels(x))[x]))`works fine thanks @akrun

Comment: @N.Varela Yes, it works well.  I thought in case you missed any numeric columns, then the `if/else` could be used.

Comment: @akrun However, the colnames gets "." instead of " ". I use country names (e.g. Antigua and Barbuda) and I need them to be the same after the conversion. Is there a way to exclude the colnames from this function?

Comment: @N.Varela I haven't tested this as there was no example data.  If you get `.` as column names, then change the column name after the conversion. i.e. `nm1 <- names(yourdat); setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(yourdat, function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])), nm1)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for(name in names(df)){
    if(is.factor(df[[name]])){
        class(df[[name]]) <- "numeric"
        #df[[name]] <- as.numeric(df[[name]])
    }
}
```

In above solution you can replace `class(df[[name]]) <- "numeric"` with `df[[name]] <- as.numeric(df[[name]])`. Both will give same result.

Example:

```
mtcars_copy <- data.frame(mpg = mtcars$mpg, cyl = mtcars$cyl, disp = as.factor(mtcars$disp))

str(mtcars_copy)
## 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  3 variables:
## $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
## $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
## $ disp: Factor w/ 27 levels "71.1","75.7",..: 13 13 6 16 23 15 23 12 10 14 ...

for(name in names(mtcars_copy)){
    if(is.factor(mtcars_copy[[name]])){
        mtcars_copy[[name]]) <- as.numeric(mtcars_copy[[name]])
    }
}

class(mtcars_copy$disp)
## [1] "integer"

str(mtcars_copy)
## 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  3 variables:
## $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
## $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
## $ disp: int  13 13 6 16 23 15 23 12 10 14 ...
```

class `numeric` is a group of many classes. class `integer` and `double` are two of those sub-classes. R auto converts between different numeric classes as per requirements.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it to work, I turned df into my df-name and the result is however NULL.

Comment: @N.Varela I've added an example. See if this solution works for you now. You don't have to convert data frame into anything. `names(df)` is a list of column names of data-frame `df`. Run `?names` in R console for more details.